# subprocess, hide output if error

Tags: python

I have a line of code like so:

```
subprocess.call('tail -n 100 -f /var/log/messages', stderr=open(os.devnull, 'wb'), shell=True)
```

If there is an error this will return the resultcode 1. Is there a way to suppress errors? Or what would be some better solution. I could trap the output in a variable and test the variable. I could check if the file exists before running the command etc. Any advice?

Comment: According to docs: _Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute._ What is exacly your problem?

Comment: @Rogalski The question is, is there a better way to do this, so that the result code is not printed. If the file does not exist I get "1" printed above as this is the result code, I don't want anything printed if there is an error.

Comment: Are you using interactive mode? It prints last operation return value by default. What about `rc = subprocess.call...`? Assignments has no return value so nothing will be printed in interactive mode.

Comment: @Rogalski, I assume the thing he's calling produces its own output, independent of the output that interactive mode might produce. Even outside of a REPL, `subprocess.call` will send text to stdout if that's what the subprocess would normally do.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call` will raise an exception if return code is other than 0.

Comment: This seems tricky to do because I'm pretty sure `call` starts printing the output of the subprocess _before_ the subprocess returns with a success or failure code. If the subprocess ordinarily does something like "print 'starting...', wait ten seconds, then return error code 1", Python won't be able to go back and erase the "starting..." message that was printed ten seconds ago.

Comment: Yes that is the issue @Kevin I guess just assigning input to a variable will have to do, and test that.

Comment: Your problem is more complex than that. `tail -f` follows the file and won't return until somebody kills it so if you are waiting for return code 0, it will be a long wait.

Comment: @tdelaney true, was just an example but that is the case indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the file exists using `os.path.exists()`.  If you also want to make sure that the path refers to a file, you could instead use `os.path.isfile()`.